# Line break within a wiki link?

Tags: mediawiki

In Mediawiki, how to insert a line break within a wikilink?

Context: An otherwise nicely balanced table is distorded (one column is very wide while the other columns are narrow) because of a very long wikilink. So I would like this link to be split in two lines.

This breaks the line, but the text is not rendered as a link:

```
[[Chargoggagoggmanchaugga<br/>goggchaubunagungamaugg]]
```

Comment: Maybe [setting widths of the columns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Table#Setting_column_widths) would be a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the same text both for link text and link target. The HTML tag can't appear in a link target, so the wiki assumes you didn't mean to generate a link.

You need to specify text and target separately:

```
 [[Chargoggagoggmanchauggagogg|Chargoggagoggmanchaugga<br/>gogg]]
```